# Calculating a limit given end behavior

Tags: calculus, limits

There exists a function $f$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = 3$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = 4$. Compute the value of $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{4+2x}{5+f(\frac{1}{x})}$$

In the numerator, plugging in $0$ is no problem – $4+2(0)$ simplifies to $4$. In the denominator, $f(\frac{1}{0})$ would be $f(\infty)$. Given the end behavior of the function, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(\infty)$ is $4$. Therefore, the denominator simplifies to $5+4$ or $9$. The limit is then equal to $\frac{4}{9}$.

Are my steps correct? I'm a little confused on plugging in $0$ into $f(\frac{1}{x})$ and getting a value. How exactly does that work mathematically speaking?

Comment: You are absolutely right. That is the best (and only as far as I know) way to do it.

Comment: To use $x\to +\infty$ for $x\,\,$ *or* $\,\,x\to 0^+$ for $\frac{1}{x}$ : It's the same.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but your notation is not. Unless you are working in the extended reals (in which case it would be explicitly stated) $\infty$ is not a number so $f(\infty)$ does not make sense, and neither does  $\frac{1}{0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps involve continuity.  A function is continuous at $a$ if you can take a limit outside the function and move it inside the function.  It turns out that $+, -, \times, \div$ are continuous everywhere except where you'd divide by $0$.  So you can write $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{4+2x}{5+f(1/x)} = \frac{\lim 4 + \lim 2x}{\lim 5 +\lim f(1/x)}.$$  You're not really "plugging in" infinity, you're just taking the limit of $f(1/x).$  And to do that, you're really saying: If $w=1/x$ then $w$ goes to $+\infty$ when $x$ goes to $0$ from the right.   So $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(1/x) = \lim_{w\rightarrow +\infty} f(w)$, and you're given this value.